# Как решить проблему с установкой дров от Nvidia?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, nvidia

Оська **Mint Olivia**(15) на **xfce**, в процессе обновления пакетов слетел sourse.list, он был восстановлен, но при этом протерялся один из pubkey'ев, в результате при установке nvidia'шных дров часть пакетов не поставилась и х-сервер при следующем запуске выдал ошибку и запретил себя вызывать. Ключ вернул на место, пакеты на видео переставил, но один пакет, а именно **ma-config.com (7.0.3.0)** настройку не прошёл. Отчёт следующий:

> ./maconfigagent: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_thread.so.1.49.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory  dpkg: ошибка при обработке параметра ma-config.com (--configure):  подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 127

Содержание отчета мне понятно, но линухсоид я неопытный, напропалую лезть не хочу(бэкап пока не сделан и не привидится), поэтому прошу подсказки.

Answer (score 1):

Это значит всего лишь, что пакет ma-config.com не соответствует обновлённой системе (из цитаты видно, что не находит нужных библиотек).

Что делать:1. Обновить (или заново переустановить) ma-config.com.2. Если не получается, то значит он несовместим с обновлённой системой, следовательно выкинуть его нафиг!

Answer (score 0):

```
aptitude updateaptitude full-upgradeapt-get -f install
```

Попробуйте так, скинте вывод.
Вот так попробуйте [ссылка](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/176).

Comment: с sudo по первой команде обновление прошло успешно, по второй:>Настраивается пакет ma-config.com (7.0.3.0)...>./maconfigagent: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_thread.so.1.49.0: cannot open shared odject file: No such file file or directory>dpkg: ошибка при обработке параметра ошибка ma-config.com (--configure): подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 127> Настраивается пакет ifupdown(0.7.5ubuntu2.2) ...> При обработке следующих параметров произошли ошибки: ma-config.com> E: Sub-procees /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code(1)

Comment: по третьей команде:>... не установлено до конца или удалено 1 пакетов>... Настраивается пакет ma-config.com (7.0.3.0)... ./maconfigagent: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_thread.so.1.49.0: cannot open shared odject file: No such file file or directory dpkg: ошибка при обработке параметра ошибка ma-config.com (--configure): подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 127 Настраивается пакет ifupdown(0.7.5ubuntu2.2) ... При обработке следующих параметров произошли ошибки: ma-config.com E: Sub-procees /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code(1)

Answer (score 0):

Попоробуйте

```
apt-get install --reinstall libboost-thread1.49.0
```

или

[найдите](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ru/saucy/libboost-thread1.49.0) этот пакет в виде deb файла и поставьте с пом-ю dpkg.

```
dpkg -i libboost-thread1.49.deb
```